# Where dinâmico Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, linq

Preciso montar uma cláusula `where` com o campo e o valor dinâmico, por exemplo, em SQL puro seria:

```
WHERE :CAMPO = :VALOR
```

Porém, vasculhando as pesquisas não consegui encontrar nada em específico, já estou realizando consultas no banco de dados com um uma cláusula `where` fixa sem problemas. Não consigo alterar dinamicamente, o meu trecho de código está da seguinte maneira:

```
string campo = "NOME";
string valor = "JOAO";

listEmpresa = db.EMPRESA.Where(...).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como você quer tudo dinâmico, existe o ótimo pacote [System.Linq.Dynamic](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/) que faz isto por você. Aí com ele seria:

```
listEmpresa = db.EMPRESA.Where(campo + "==@0", valor).ToList();
```

Comment: mas no caso, o e.Nome seria dinamico, e o valor "JOAO" também, eu precisaria passar o nome das variáveis no caso...

Comment: Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Ah! Eu tinha editado para passar `"JOAO"` em uma variável, mas não deu tempo... rs

Comment: @AndreR, vc pode fazer assim: 
`var nomeParaPesquisar = "JOAO";`
`listEmpresa = db.EMPRESA.Where(e => e.Nome == nomeParaPesquisar).ToList();`

Comment: @ThiagoLunardi Acho que ele quer montar tudo dinâmico, aí tem que ser pelo System.Linq.Dynamic mesmo.

Comment: @ThiagoLunardi Parece que ele precisa passar o **campo** dinamicamente também.

Comment: obrigado Cigano, consegui resolver o problema, abraços!

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, esse `Where` dinâmico tem algum risco de permitir SQL Injection (no caso no nome do campo, já que o valor ta parametrizado)? Ou o ORM já se previne de alguma forma em relação a isso?

Comment: @Fernando A parametrização é feita através de `SqlParameters`. No mais, o tratamento das variáveis deve receber alguma atenção do programador.

Answer (score 5):

Eu estou trabalhando com isso atualmente, e recomendo utilizar `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`, `Lambda` e um pouco de `Reflection` para isso.

Exemplo:

```
string campo = "Campo";
string valor = "valor";

// recupera o objeto IQueryable da Context do EF
IQueryable<Empresa> query = db.EMPRESA;
// cria alias do objecto Lambda
ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Empresa), "x");
// obtem tipo da propriedade
Type type = typeof(Empresa).GetProperty(campo).PropertyType;
// cria Expression para o campo
MemberExpression propertyExpression = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, campo);
// cria Expression para o valor
ConstantExpression valueExpression = Expression.Constant(Convert.ChangeType(valor, type), type);
```

**EXEMPLO Equals**

```
// cria predicate Lambda Expression
var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Empresa, bool>>(
    // aplica tipo de Filtro, no caso do exemplo Equal (campo == valor)
    Expression.Equal(propertyExpression, valueExpression)
, param);
```

**EXEMPLO Contains (LIKE)**

```
MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod("Contains", new[] { type });            
var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Empresa, bool>>(
    // aplica tipo de Filtro, no caso do exemplo Contains (LIKE campo '%valor%')
    Expression.Call(propertyExpression, methodInfo, valueExpression)
, param);
```

Continuação código...

```
// adiciona predicate ao where da query
query = query.Where(predicate);
// executa a consulta no banco de dados
var result = query.ToList();
```

Fonte: [Use string as field name in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11204998/2290538)

Comment: muito obrigado, Fernando!

Comment: @AndreR só pra constar: você só pode escolher uma resposta como correta.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode também estender o `System.Linq` adicionando um `WhereIf`. Eu usei uma vez, e funciona bacaninha.

Primeiro adicionar a extenção no seu projeto:

```
public static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<TSource> WhereIf<TSource>(
        this IQueryable<TSource> source, bool condition,
        Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate)
    {
        if (!condition) return source;
        return source.Where(predicate);            
    }
}
```

Depois usa com sabedoria:

```
// a clausula WHERE somente será aplicado se variável 'condicao' for true
var resultado = MeusDados
                    .WhereIf(condicao == true, dado => dado.campo == "valor")
                    .ToList();
```

UPDATE:

Exemplo de aplicação:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IEnumerable<pessoa>> BuscarPessoas(string nome, int idade, DateTime dataNascimento)
{
    var pessoas = await Task.FromResult(_contexto.Pessoas
                      .WhereIf(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nome), p => p.Nome.Contains(nome))
                      .WhereIf(idade > 0, p => p.Idade == idade)
                      .WhereIf(dataNascimento != null, p => p.DataNascimento = dataNascimento)
                      .ToList();
    return pessoas;
}
```

Comment: Eu não quero parecer chato. Mas não consigo ver como, usando esta solução, o campo do where seria passado dinamicamente.

Comment: muito obrigado de qualquer forma Thiago, abraço!

Comment: Tem razão @jbueno , literalmente, não seria. Mandei pq eu jamais faria algo do tipo, pois acho que é inseguro, pois aceitaria **SQL Injection**, sei lá. Eu faria o seguinte, no front escolhe por qual campo vai filtrar no back faria um WhereIf para cara campo possível.

Comment: Mas acredite, é uma maneira bem legal de lidar. Eu gosto, acho super limpo, e é rápido. :)

Comment: @ThiagoLunardi, eu tentei entender como esse `WhereIf` pode ajudar no problema da pergunta e não encontrei relação. Pode tentar editar para ser mais claro com sua resposta e como ela ajuda a resolver o problema da pergunta? Pois da forma que está não vejo muita vantagem em utiliza-la ao invés do `Where` normal!

Comment: @Fernando, adicionei um exemplo de aplicação. Veja se atende, pf?

Comment: @ThiagoLunardi, o que não vejo na sua solução é como utilizar o nome da coluna/propriedade dinâmico, apartir de uma string, que é o problema relatado na pergunta?

Comment: @Fernando, Linq é fortemente tipado. LambdaExpression trabalha apenas com predicados. Então, sem usar *workarounds* não é possível.

Comment: @ThiagoLunardi, então sua resposta não responde a pergunta, pois a principal questão da pergunta é como criar consultas com campo dinâmico. Concordo que é uma boa solução para validar registros antes de adiciona-los no `Where`. Mas no meu entendimento não tem real relação com a pergunta (posso estar errado =D). E no caso a pergunta quer realmente uma forma alternativa (_workarounds_), e a sua extensão também já é uma forma alternativa. =/