# Como alterar a estrutura de uma consulta LINQ em tempo de execução?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

Possuo o seguinte exemplo de um programa que implementa o EF (Entity Framework). A estrutura do banco e da aplicação esta definida da seguinte forma:

Tabela `Pessoa`:

- Campo chave primaria: `id_pessoa`
- Campo nome: `nome`
- Campo idade: `idade`

Classe `Pessoa` construída a partir da tabela `pessoa` do banco de dados pelo EF:

```
namespace EFPessoaExemplo
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class Pessoa
    {
        public int id_pessoa { get; set; }
        public string nome { get; set; }
        public int idade { get; set; }
    }
}
```

E o método responsável pela consulta Linq:

```
private void lerPessoa(string nome, bool maiorIdade) 
{
    using (BancoEFEntities context = new BancoEFEntities()) 
    {
        IEnumerable<Pessoa> pessoa = from p in context.Pessoa 
                                     where p.nome.Contains(nome) 
                                     select p;

        dataGridViewPessoa.DataSource = pessoa.ToList();
    }
}
```

---

## Minha dúvida

No método `lerPessoa(string nome, bool maiorIdade)`, eu gostaria de saber se é possível alterar a estrutura da consulta feita em LINQ em tempo de execução para acrescentar uma condição a mais, que neste caso é o segundo parâmetro do método `maiorIdade`, caso o valor da variável `maiorIdade` seja `true` a condição `p.idade >= 18` deve ser especificada a cláusula `where`.

Existe uma forma de fazer isso sem ter que criar uma consulta LINQ inteira para cada condição?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acho que é isto que deseja:

```
private void lerPessoa(string nome, bool maiorIdade) {
    using (BancoEFEntities context = new BancoEFEntities()) {
        var pessoa = from p in context.Pessoa 
                                     where p.nome.Contains(nome) 
                                     select p;
        if (maiorIdade) {
            pessoa = from p in pessoa
                     where p.idade >= 18
                     select p;
        }
        dataGridViewPessoa.DataSource = pessoa.ToList();
    }
}
```

O LINQ é aplicável à qualquer estrutura enumerável. O resultado de uma consulta LINQ é uma estrutura enumerável. Note que a declaração foi mudada para `var` para que não force a concretização da *query*.

Outra forma para ajudar no problema conforme comentário do AP:

```
private void lerPessoa(string nome, bool maiorIdade) {
    using (BancoEFEntities context = new BancoEFEntities()) {
        IEnumerable<Pessoa> pessoa = from p in context.Pessoa 
                                     where p.nome.Contains(nome) && (!maiorIdade || p.idade >= 18)
                                     select p;
        dataGridViewPessoa.DataSource = pessoa.ToList();
    }
}
```

Essa forma pode ser problemática para a geração do SQL. Como eu não tenho experiência com EF não sei explicar o motivo, mas faz sentido já que existem informações espúrias na *query*. Conforme comentários abaixo, o Cigano também entende o mesmo, mas não deu explicação do motivo. Não aconselho o uso no EF.

O que talvez deseje para simplificar é usar a [forma imperativa no lugar da declarativa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14212/101). A forma declarativa é bonitinha, mas frequentemente ela acaba sendo menos concisa que a forma imperativa. A solução então talvez seja trocar a forma de escrita:

```
private void lerPessoa(string nome, bool maiorIdade) {
    using (BancoEFEntities context = new BancoEFEntities()) {
        var pessoa = context.Pessoa.Where(p => p.nome.Contains(nome));
        if (maiorIdade) pessoa = pessoa.Where(p => p.idade >= 18);
        dataGridViewPessoa.DataSource = pessoa.ToList();
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/BuildQuery.cs).

Não vejo forma melhor.

Comment: Neste caso, será necessário reescrever a estrutura básica do linq para cada condição? Seria possível fazer uma concatenação como as consultas SQLs?

Comment: @drmcarvalho Sim, pode, adicionei.

Comment: A alguma resposta aqui no SOpt que explica o que é uma estrutura enumerável?

Comment: Provavelmente http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17284/101. Esta ajuda um pouco http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125601/101 e também http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129810/101 e finalmente http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44293/101. Se nenhuma satisfazer, aí não :)

Comment: Esta resposta está incorreta. O autor da pergunta quer geração dinâmica de SQL. A primeira proposta faz dois SQL's disjuntos, e a segunda é um artifício técnico.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez é verdade, mas há algum problema na segunda? As demais respostas estão corretas? Por que?

Comment: Você está resolvendo em todos os casos para `IEnumerable`, que executa o SQL. Não é isso que o autor da pergunta quer. Ele quer montar o SQL condicionalmente antes de executar.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Mas as outras respostas estão certas? Só porque não tem um tipo definido?

Comment: Não, não é apenas por isso. A essência da resposta está em não usar `IEnumerable`. Como se sabe, `IEnumerable` força a resolução da sentença inteira. Não só o `IEnumerable` como o `ToList()`. O segundo caso é ainda pior porque você está criando uma condicional que não precisa ir para o SQL.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez então não entendi porque as outras respostas estão corretas se no fundo fazem a mesma coisa, só que usaram o `var`.

Comment: Porque o `var` usa inferência dinâmica. Não resolve para `IEnumerable` e, portanto, não executa a pesquisa. A pesquisa só é executada na chamada de `ToList()`.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez até aí eu concordo e vou arrumar, mas você disse que não é o único problema.

Comment: Isto aqui é um problema enorme: `where p.nome.Contains(nome) && (!maiorIdade || p.idade >= 18)`

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez E não acontece o mesmo em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/130811/101?

Comment: Não. O método de extensão não devolve `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez tudo bem, esse problema eu entendo, não entendi porque a expressão é problemática e o método de extensão que faz a mesma coisa não é.

Answer (score 5):

No exemplo abaixo utilizo Linq com expressões Lambda para não repetir o código.

Fica assim:

```
private void lerPessoa(string nome, bool maiorIdade) 
{
    using (BancoEFEntities context = new BancoEFEntities()) 
    {
      var query = from p in context.Pessoa 
                                 where p.nome.Contains(nome) 
                                 select p;

       if(maiorIdade)
          //aqui minha query vai receber uma nova comparação
          //por isso usa-se o query.Where
          //dê um nome para o objeto, no meu caso utilizei "p". O objeto deve seguir de =>
          //depois de fazer isso o Where espera uma expressão booleana
          //ou seja dentro do Where sempre tem que ter uma expressão de comparação
          //agora será filtrado os objetos que satisfaçam a comparação
          //portanto quando você der um query.ToList() retornará apenas pessoas que tenham idade acima de 17 anos.
          query = query.Where(p=> p.idade >= 18);

       dataGridViewPessoa.DataSource = query.ToList();
    }
}
```

Planeje seu código para reuso

```
private IList<Pessoa> listarPessoas(string nome, bool maiorIdade) {
   using(var context = new BancoEFEntities()) {

       var query = from p in context.Pessoa
                                     where p.nome.Contains(nome)
                                     select p;
       if(maiorIdade)
           query = query.Where(p=> p.idade >=18);
       return query.ToList();
   }
}


private void SeuMétodo()
{
   gridView.DataSource = lerPessoa('nome', false);
}
```

Comment: Seria interessante você explicar que seu `Where`, não é somente [`Linq`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb397926.aspx) e sim [`Lambda Expression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb397687.aspx) com `Linq`, só para ficar mais claro a quem não conhece. A solução em si esta perfeita.

Comment: Obrigado Fernando, vou fazer esse ajuste.

Answer (score 4):

Para situações assim, eu gosto de estender a classe LINQ e usar o `WhereIf`. O bacana desse método é se tem o controle do que será ou não enviado para o ORM resolver - e se ele não resolver, mandará para o banco de dados cláusulas que poderiam ser ignoradas.

Eu escrevi sobre isso [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/125421/where-din%C3%A2mico-linq-to-sql/125443#125443).

Primeiro adicionar a extensão no seu projeto:

```
public static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<TSource> WhereIf<TSource>(
        this IQueryable<TSource> source, bool condition,
        Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate)
    {
        if (!condition) return source;
        return source.Where(predicate);            
    }
}
```

Depois use com sabedoria:

```
// a clausula WHERE somente será aplicado se variável 'condicao' for true
var resultado = MeusDados
                    .WhereIf(condicao == true, dado => dado.campo == "valor")
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: Nesta pergunta **Sim** o `WhereIf` se encaixa, hehe! Clausuras dinâmicas. +1